# Site malware (trojan) keeps coming every time

Tags: trojan

Recently I discovered that a lot of websites I built were infected with malware.

The first thing I did was download all the contents of the websites to my local PC, and provided a scan with Windows Security Essentials on it. WSE discovered a trojan on the index.php of a few (4/15) websites. After repairing the indexes I uploaded all the contents to my web server, and the problem was solved.

But not for long.. A month later the problem came back. In the meantime I purchased an new laptop, with a clean Windows 7 installation. I did the same trick I did earlier (the first time I discovered the malware), and it resulted also in finding a couple of trojans. After repairing and uploading the problems were solved.

But also this time the problems keep returning, and I don't know what to do anymore.
Does anybody have experience with such problems?

A list of sites infected with the malware:

- maurijnpach.nl
- banket-ritmeester.nl
- mtbmuseum.nl
- dekipspecialist.nl

The only thing I am thinking about is that all the websites are hosted on one the same hosting provider: [Webreus](https://www.webreus.nl/)

Does anybody have any suggestions, or better, a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your host is leaked or "something". You said nothing about your sites. Maybe just bad/open for malware code. Are you using some cms? Check files/folders permissions and change passwords for ftp/MySql. And tell more about your sites structure.

For me it looking like a server intrusion. Talk with your host and change password for better ones.